# Bash Script to move file from one Ubuntu server to another server

Tags: bash, scripts

I am looking for a bash script that can move files from one Ubuntu server to another Ubuntu server
with day -1

Comment: Hello post the script you have made and maybe someone can see the errors if it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are moving a file with a known structure that contains a date string that looks like `YYYY-MM-DD` via `scp`, you can do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

scp /path/to/files/database_backup_$(date -d "yesterday" '+%Y-%m-%d').sql.gz user@server:/path/of/destination/database_backup_$(date -d "yesterday" '+%Y-%m-%d').sql.gz
```

**Notes:**

1. `date -d "yesterday" '+%Y-%m-%d'` will format yesterday's date as `YYYY-MM-DD`
2. be sure to replace the source directory with the correct path and file name structure
3. be sure to replace the destination directory with the correct path and file name structure
4. this is not meant to be a final solution, but the start of one that provides you the basics that you can build from

Comment: You don't need to specify the remote file name, only the dir: `scp /path/to/files/database_backup_$(date -d "yesterday" '+%Y-%m-%d').sql.gz user@server:/path/of/destination/`.

Comment: thanks very much :)